# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0, but Angular version 14.2.12 was found instead

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular13, angular14

My global CLI version:
[ng version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPYsE.png)

My project CLI version:
[ng version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DgBw.png)

My Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/common": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/forms": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.12",
  "@angular/router": "^14.2.12",
  "angular-component-library": "16.0.0-beta.1",
  "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.2",
  "@angular/cli": "~15.0.4",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.0.4",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
  "karma": "~6.3.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
  "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
  "tslint": "~5.15.0",
  "typescript": "~4.6.2"
}
```

on **ng serve**, I see the following error

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0,
> but Angular version 14.2.12 was found instead.

Tried playing around by installing and uninstalling multiple CLI versions but nothing helped resolve this. Looking for some help/insights on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You global can be higner than whats in your dev dependacies. Just keep the versions the same. these 3 seems off compared to the rest.

```
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.2",
  "@angular/cli": "~15.0.4",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.0.4",
```

the reest is version `14.2.12`

a simple fix would be change these to

```
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.12",
  "@angular/cli": "~14.2.12",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.12",
```

and just run `npm install`